# Why does pid0 get printed twice with a value when forking?

Tags: c, fork

I am struggling to understand why the variable pid0 gets printed twice with an actual id. As I have understood it, pid0 will be set to 0 for all of the forked processes after the first time.

This is my main function:

```
int main() {
  pid_t pid0, pid1, pid2;

  pid0 = fork();
  pid1 = fork();
  if (pid0 == 0) pid2 = fork();

  printf("pid0: %d, pid1: %d, pid2: %d\n", pid0, pid1, pid2);

  return 0;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
pid0: 3388, pid1: 3389, pid2: 32766
pid0: 3388, pid1: 0, pid2: 32766
pid0: 0, pid1: 3390, pid2: 3391
pid0: 0, pid1: 0, pid2: 3392
pid0: 0, pid1: 3390, pid2: 0
pid0: 0, pid1: 0, pid2: 0
```

Comment: You have 6 processes.  For the first 4 that you create, `pid0` will be `0` for half of them, and non-zero for the other half.  That's two.  After the first fork, `pid0` is non-zero for one process.  You then fork again, so now it's non-zero for two processes.

Comment: Note that you don't always initialize `pid2`, which is why you get some interesting values printed.  Make sure variables are initialized properly.

Comment: regarding the function: `fork()` This has three(3) different return states: <0 means an error occurred.  ==0 means in the child process,  >0 means in the parent process.  The posted code is failing to check for all three conditions so does not act correctly for all cases.  In general, code should NOT act the same for all three cases. I..E it is a poor programming practice for all three cases to be treated the same and/or be allowed to execute into each other

Comment: the 'pid2' value of `32766`  is just the trash in memory/stack where the variable `pid2` is declared, before it is set to some specific value

Comment: a Parent process should not be allowed to exit until all its' Child processes have exited.  The functions: `wait()` and `waitpid()` are made for waiting for child process to exit.   However, those functions will return as soon as a child process changes state.  Therefore, the function will need to be called multiple time, depending on how many child processes are children of that current parent.  having the parent exit before all its' child processes (used to) result in turning a child process into a zombie process.  In todays' linux rather than zombie, the process is attached to `init`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `fork()` creates a second process. Your second one runs on *both* processes and you've then got four processes. Two of these have `pid0` set to `0`, the other two do not.

The original forked process (`pid0 === 0`) and its clone will both call `fork()` again, so there's two more processes, for six total.

Of these four are part of the original `fork()` tree, and two are also in the secondary tree (`pid1 == 0`).

If you want only one parent process you must gate the second `fork()` and avoid doing it if `pid0` is non-zero.

Notice the second line of your output has `pid1: 0` which indicates it's a clone.

Comment: actually, not exactly a clone, but a child process that executes its' own code within the process

Comment: @user3629249 It's a separate process, it has its own PID, memory and such and only shares very specific things like filehandles. It's a child process initially but can be detached, at which point it's fully independent. Are you thinking of threads when meaning "executes its own code within the process"?

Answer (score 2):

After you fork, both the parent and child continue executing the following code.

Let's call the original process `P`, and the child created with `pid0 = fork()` `P-C1`. Both of these processes then execute `pid1 = fork()`. We then have two more processes, which I'll call `P-C2` and `P-C1-C3`.

Now all 4 processes execute the `if` statement. `pid0` is `0` in both `P-C1` and `P-C1-C3`, so they both execute `pid2 = fork()`. This creates processes `P-C1-C4` and `P-C1-C3-C5`, and they inherit the zero value of `pid0`.

When all this is done, we have `pid0 = 0` in processes `P-C1`, `P-C1-C3`, `P-C1-C4`, and `P-C1-C3-C4`. And `pid0 != 0` in processes `P` and `P-C2`.

All 6 of these processes then print `pid0`.